# How to set and get fields in struct's method

Tags: struct, get, set, go

After creating a struct like this:

```
type Foo struct {
    name string
}

func (f Foo) SetName(name string) {
    f.name = name
}

func (f Foo) GetName() string {
    return f.name
}
```

How do I create a new instance of Foo and set and get the name?
I tried the following:

```
p := new(Foo)
p.SetName("Abc")
name := p.GetName()

fmt.Println(name)
```

Nothing gets printed, because name is empty. So how do I set and get a field inside a struct?

[Working playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_xkIc-n6Wbk)

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Commentary (and working) example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    name string
}

// SetName receives a pointer to Foo so it can modify it.
func (f *Foo) SetName(name string) {
    f.name = name
}

// Name receives a copy of Foo since it doesn't need to modify it.
func (f Foo) Name() string {
    return f.name
}

func main() {
    // Notice the Foo{}. The new(Foo) was just a syntactic sugar for &Foo{}
    // and we don't need a pointer to the Foo, so I replaced it.
    // Not relevant to the problem, though.
    p := Foo{}
    p.SetName("Abc")
    name := p.Name()
    fmt.Println(name)
}
```

[Test it](http://play.golang.org/p/Pw9f20zwja) and take [A Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org) to learn more about methods and pointers, and the basics of Go at all.

Comment: Name() would be the idiomatic name for the getter (see http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters)

Comment: How expensive is the getter if it requires a copy? Does it actually copy the entire struct?

Comment: @Kugel Yes, the getter does copy the entire struct. Don't worry about the copy being expensive, unless your struct is exceptionally heavy. It's a memory copy, not a hard drive copy.

Comment: Why can't we pass the pointer all the time, and not edit it if we don't want to? Does it have anything to do with concurrent updates?

Comment: @Shashwat Receiving by value is essentially saying this method doesn't modify that struct, and makes it less likely for anyone to make a breaking change to that method further down the road, including yourself. Never forget other pieces of your code may depend on that same struct and break if it's modified unexpectedly.

Comment: how do I set nested struct?

Comment: If you don't use functions to set your property names, how do you make use of interfaces? Its easy to adapt a struct with getters and setters to conform to an interface, its much harder when you have a struct that is open to updates from any code which has a reference to it.

Answer (score 34):

Setters and getters are not **that** idiomatic to Go.
Especially the getter for a field x is not named GetX 
but just X.
See http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters

If the setter does not provide special logic, e.g.
validation logic, there is nothing wrong with exporting
the field and neither providing a setter nor a getter
method. (This just feels wrong for someone with a 
Java background. But it is not.)

Comment: Part of the reason for information hiding (encapsulation) is program evolution. You simply don't splutter your code everywhere with direct access. Lets say after 1 year, you do decide to implement validation or something even a little bit different. You don't want to refactor a thousand different places but just a single file and a single place. Throwing out established practices and thought from other languages isn't ALWAYS the right thing to do.

Comment: @sat If you have to refactor a thousand places, maybe you are doing something wrong in the first place.

Comment: @sat (and all the upvoters): Refactoring several thousand call sites in Go is not that complicated. Gofix still exists and other tools are maturing fast. Last not least: Wrapping all access just because you might want to change this access violates YAGNI and helps only if you refactoring **can** be done by changing the getter alone (no extra error case, no other refactorings). I heard these kind of arguments far too often. If the API is well designed you won't face these problems and if the API is bad your lost anyway.

Comment: Adding a Setter/Getter to every single public property of all your classes/objects/structs is a waste of both human and machine time. I don't add logic to every public variable/pointer assignment for the same reason I don't wrap all string + concatenation in a custom `append(a, b)` function.

Answer (score 7):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    name string
}

func (f *Foo) SetName(name string) {
    f.name = name
}

func (f *Foo) Name() string {
    return f.name
}

func main() {
    p := new(Foo)
    p.SetName("Abc")
    name := p.Name()
    fmt.Println(name)
}
```

Output:

```
Abc
```

Comment: While technically your answer will work, GetFoo() is not the idiomatic getter naming for Foo in Go : it should be just Foo(). More details in Zippoxer's answer.

Comment: it's a good example , but for the `GetName()` method you don't need to pass it by a pointer `func(f *Foo)` you should be fine with `func(f Foo)` because you don't modify the value you just read/return it.

Comment: @Hoenir: "Choosing whether to use a value or pointer receiver on methods can be difficult, especially to new Go programmers. If in doubt, use a pointer." [Receiver Type, Go Code Review Comments](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-type). This is a contrived example, we don't know how large the actual struct will be. Therefore, we use a pointer.

Comment: @peterSO "A value receiver can reduce the amount of garbage that can be generated"
And for this simple example it'a a waste to use a reciver.And the struct is not "large" enogh to even make sense to use the pointer.

Comment: @Hoenir: I repeat. This is a contrived example. It's not a real example.