# How can I choose between "updateSomething" and "setSomething" when naming a member method?

Tags: go, naming-conventions

I have found at least three world `setSth`,`updateSth` and `updateSth` appear in my code when I naming a method whose function is set/update the state of `this` object.

I'm confuse this choosing.
I search source code of golang project and found there have many one using `setSth`.

- **0 items using "changeSth"**
- **8 items using "updateSth"**

  > ```
  > text/tabwriter/tabwriter.go
  > 380:func (b *Writer) updateWidth() {
  > go/ast/commentmap.go
  > 246:func (cmap CommentMap) Update(old, new Node) Node {
  >
  > container/heap/example_pq_test.go
  > 54:func (pq *PriorityQueue) update(item *Item, value string, priority int) {
  >
  > expvar/expvar.go
  > 129:func (v *Map) updateKeys() {
  >
  > encoding/gob/encode.go
  > 101:func (state *encoderState) update(instr *encInstr) {
  >
  > crypto/cipher/gcm.go
  > 236:func (g *gcm) updateBlocks(y *gcmFieldElement, blocks []byte) {
  > 247:func (g *gcm) update(y *gcmFieldElement, data []byte) {
  >
  > index/suffixarray/qsufsort.go
  > 145:func (x *suffixSortable) updateGroups(offset int) {
  > ```
- **214 items using "setSth"**

  > net/fd_plan9.go:214:func (fd *netFD) setReadDeadline(t time.Time)
  >
  > error { net/fd_plan9.go:218:func (fd *netFD) setWriteDeadline(t
  >
  > time.Time) error { mime/multipart/writer.go:43:func (w *Writer)
  >
  > SetBoundary(boundary string) error { log/log.go:218:func (l *Logger)
  >
  > SetFlags(flag int) { log/log.go:232:func (l *Logger) SetPrefix(prefix
  >
  > string) { bufio/scan.go:198:func (s *Scanner) setErr(err error) {
  >
  > archive/zip/struct.go:185:func (h *FileHeader) SetModTime(t time.Time)
  >
  > { archive/zip/struct.go:223:func (h *FileHeader) SetMode(mode
  >
  > os.FileMode) { expvar/expvar.go:60:func (v *Int) Set(value int64) {
  >
  > expvar/expvar.go:86:func (v *Float) Set(value float64) {
  >
  > expvar/expvar.go:147:func (v *Map) Set(key string, av Var) {
  >
  > expvar/expvar.go:228:func (v *String) Set(value string) {
  >
  > testing/benchmark.go:97:func (b *B) SetBytes(n int64) { b.bytes = n }
  >
  > testing/benchmark.go:430:func (b *B) SetParallelism(p int) {
  >
  > image/image.go:92:func (p *RGBA) Set(x, y int, c color.Color) {
  >
  > image/image.go:104:func (p *RGBA) SetRGBA(x, y int, c color.RGBA) {
  >
  > image/image.go:196:func (p *RGBA64) Set(x, y int, c color.Color) {

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key remains consistency:

- when you start using "`UpdateXXX()`" in a package, stick with it.
- same thing if you are using `SetXXX()`.

That being said, `Get` and `Set` are not idiomatic in Go. Certainly [not for a Getter](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters), while a setter function, if needed, will likely be called `SetXXX()`, as in "[how to set and get fields in golang structs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11810342/6309)".
`Update()`, on the other hand, might have a specific purpose.

Note: none of the "`update()`" methods you have found in the go source are exported (public).

Comment: So there haven't inherent different between `Set` and `Update` ?
Using which one is only determined by consistency or language?

Comment: @snyh In general, `Update` if for something already set, that you want to change. `Set` is for setting a value, regardless if it was already set or not.

Comment: last curiousness. Does the `changeSth` is totally wrong? I used to choose this one :(

Comment: @snyh as long as you don't mix change and update, meaning as long as you chose one convention and use it consistently, there is nothing wrong with change().