# Go, write struct fields in function

Tags: go, struct

I am new in Go and I don't understand why the struct field values are not written if I don't use a pointer in the struct functions. Here an example, when setValue() is called, it executes but the value is not set:

```
type myStruct struct {
    value string
}

func (m myStruct) getValue() string            { return m.value }
func (m myStruct) setValue(val string)         { m.value = val }
func (m *myStruct) getValuePointer() string    { return m.value }
func (m *myStruct) setValuePointer(val string) { m.value = val }

func TestStruct(t *testing.T) {
    obj := myStruct{value: "initValue"}

    fmt.Printf("Use setValue function\n")
    obj.setValue("setValue_Called")
    fmt.Printf("obj.getValue()        = [%v]\n", obj.getValue())
    fmt.Printf("obj.getValuePointer() = [%v]\n", obj.getValuePointer())

    fmt.Printf("Use setValuePointer function\n")
    obj.setValuePointer("setValuePointer_Called")
    fmt.Printf("obj.getValue()        = [%v]\n", obj.getValue())
    fmt.Printf("obj.getValuePointer() = [%v]\n", obj.getValuePointer())
}
```

this code prints:

```
Use setValue function
obj.getValue()        = [initValue]
obj.getValuePointer() = [initValue]
Use setValuePointer function
obj.getValue()        = [setValuePointer_Called]
obj.getValuePointer() = [setValuePointer_Called]
```

Could someone help me understanding what happens under the hood when a struct function is created using or not using a pointer?
In addition, the fact that setValue executes with no errors or warnings is quite scaring to me :(

Comment: Does https://tour.golang.org/methods/4 help, or do you still have questions after reading that?

Comment: The most significant part of that page: "With a value receiver, the Scale method operates on a copy of the original Vertex value. (This is the same behavior as for any other function argument.)"

Comment: @smarx thanks, it helps but it does not solve all my doubts about what really happens. What does it mean exactly "With a value receiver, the Scale method operates on a copy of the original Vertex value."? Does it mean that a new instance of the struct will be created on the fly and all the original instance fields will be duplicated recursively? So if a huge object it passed as a value receiver it could fill all the available memory?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is essentially correct.

Comment: This is a 100% duplicate. This question gets asked a lot an the internet is full of explanations, including the official documentation of Go.

Comment: @Volker Then find the right question and vote to close this as a duplicate of it.

Comment: @FrancescoCina "So if a huge object it passed as a value receiver it could fill all the available memory?" No, because no such large object are common in Go. There is **absolutely** no reason to be concerned about this copy operation. It is _really_ hard to produce a struct where this copy is noticeable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810218/how-to-set-and-get-fields-in-golang-structs and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to remember while you were defining methods is:

Methods are like normal functions, and when you were calling `setValue()` function, what's happening is this.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type vertex struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func main() {
    var v vertex
    fmt.Println(v.setVertex(1, 2))
    fmt.Println(v)
/*  v = v.setVertex(1,2)
    // we are assigning the returned variable address to v.
    fmt.Println(v)
*/

}


// With a value receiver, the setVertex method operates on a copy of the 
// original vertex value. (This is the same behavior as for any other
// function argument.) 
// This methods has a value as a reciver, so it gets the copy not the 
// original vertex.

func (v vertex) setVertex(x, y int) vertex {
// Here it is similar to creating a new variable with name 'v',
// Go is lexically scoped using blocks, so this variable exists only 
// in this block, while it is returned we are printing it but we didn't
// store it in another variable.
    v.x = x
    v.y = y
    return v
}

// If you want to change any variable or struct, we need to pass its 
// address, else only copy of that variable is received by the called
// function.
```

This is clearly explained in [gotour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/4)